# Is installshield suited in this scenario?

Tags: mysql, exe, installshield

The scenario my company asked me to find solution is,

1. Install MySql
2. Create Users and grand privileges
3. Create a database
4. Install Multiple exe files
5. Run 3-4 sql scripts.

Ok so i saw InstallShield features, i was looking at NSIS option too but my company dont care if we will buy InstallShield or use a free one so i dropped this options, after 2-3 hours of researching i found that installshield is probably the best.

But i have 0 experience in this field and i cant tell for sure if InstallShield can meet my needs or if im overthinking this scenario and there is a simple solution.

Any advise is appriciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specific scenario for a windows installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828482/specific-scenario-for-a-windows-installer)

Comment: Please don't double post.  InstallShield *CAN* do these things but I really don't recommend it.  See my comments and answer in the other question.  Choosing NSIS doesn't matter but in fact would be even harder.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend everyone to not go with InstallShield. Better go with WiX (Windows Installer XML).

In our company we used InstallShield MSI-Project for a half decade and it's really a pain. When you try the demo-version everything looks nice and polished but as soon you get more and more requirements you will start to notice that there are many bugs and using InstallScript for custom actions will bring you back in the 90s.

The syntax of WiX (which is pure XML) will look confusing and hard to read in the first time but it's so good to have makros and variables that you can use in your markup on your side.

You can write your Custom Actions in C# and therefore you are able to use some existing code for creating users and grant privileges.