# Specific scenario for a windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, exe, installshield

I have this scenario, we developed a windows application and it have a prerequisite of mysql, so we need to:

1.Install MySql
2.Create Users and grand privileges
3.Create a database
4.Install Multiple exe files
5.Run 3-4 sql scripts.

We want to make a single installation if possible or a wizard to install everything 1 by 1, after some research I saw InstallShield and NSIS, but I have 0 experience in mking installers,

Anyone have any suggestion for a solution in this scenario?

Comment: The only real solution is to get that number 0 up.  Do note that it is very rare that you can do this properly in an installer.  Particularly picking users, assigning rights, choosing a server and create proper backup plans are the job of a DBA.  Hiding a dbase invariably leads to tears when the machine falls over and the data is lost irretrievably.

Comment: In all my years I've only worked at 1 company where they were able to get a really good SQL DB story in their installer. This was because they were an SOA story with dozens of tiny databases and they hired a crew of DBA contractors to work with me to perfect the story.  Everywhere else hasn't ended so well.  See: http://blog.iswix.com/2008/10/rfc-sql-scripts-are-almost-declared.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstallShield can technically do all of those things but I'd really suggest not trying to do it in the installer.  If you look at installer for big database dependent products like Microsoft Team Foundation Server you'll see they have outsourced all of this to a configuration wizard that gets run post installation.   The wizard gathers up all of the connection information ( the database engine might not even be on this machine )  and has all the logic to make everything happy including security and maintenance plans.